# counting unique values Algorithms

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function countUniqueValues(arr){
    if(arr.length === 0) return 0;
    var i = 0;
    for(var j = 1; j < arr.length; j++){
        if(arr[i] !== arr[j]){
            i++;
            arr[i] = arr[j]
        }
    }
    return i + 1;
}
countUniqueValues([1,2,2,5,7,7,99])
```

I am studying algorithm using Javascript. The question is as follows :
Implement a function called countUniqueValues, which accepts a sorted array, and count the unique values in the array. There can be negative numbers in the array, but it will always be sorted.

The above is the answer in the lecture, but I am having trouble understanding why you need

```
arr[i] = arr[j]
```

as you just need the value of i to increase to see the number of unique values using the array index. Can anyone explain me why we need

```
arr[i] = arr[j]
```

Comment: using ````arr[i] = arr[j] ````` arr[i] will always be the last unique value found in the array.

Comment: You don't need it. It's a bad solution by the lecturer. It mutates the array for no reason

Comment: You just need to check if the current and previous elements are not same: `let count = 0; for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { if (arr[i] !== arr[i-1]) count++ }`

Answer (score 1):

```
arr[i] = arr[j]
```

This means exactly this. If two array elements are equal, they must be counted as one. Hence, it singles out the two array elements. Update array when there is no equality.

Lets write step by step.

```
i=0
j=1
Loop 1:
arr[i=0](1) !== arr[j=1](2)
i+1(i=1)
arr[1]=arr[1](2)

Loop 1 Result:
i=1  arr[1]=2  
Old Array:([1,2,2,5,7,7,99])
New Array:([1,2,2,5,7,7,99])

Loop 2:
arr[i=1](2) == arr[j=2](2)
//Do Nothing

Loop 2 Result:
i=1 arr[1]=2     

Loop 3:
arr[i=1](2) !== arr[j=3](5)
i+1(i=2)
arr[2]=arr[3](5)

Loop 3 Result:
i=2 arr[2]=5
Old Array:([1,2,2,5,7,7,99])
New Array:([1,2,5,5,7,7,99])

Loop 4:
arr[i=2](5) !== arr[j=4](7)
i+1(i=3)
j+1(j=5)
arr[3]=arr[4](7)

Loop 4 Result:
i=3 arr[3]=7
Old Array:([1,2,5,5,7,7,99])
New Array:([1,2,5,7,7,7,99])

Loop 5:
arr[i=3](7) == arr[j=5](7)
j+1
//Do Nothing

Loop 5 Result:
i=3 j=6

Loop 6:
arr[i=3](7) !== arr[j=6](99)
i+1(i=4)
j+1(j=7)
arr[4]=arr[6](99)


Loop 6 Result:
i=4 arr[4]=99
Old Array:([1,2,5,7,7,7,99])
New Array:([1,2,5,7,99,7,99])
```

.
.
.
.

FINAL

```
i=4
Last Array:([1,2,5,7,99])
```

You can reach the result with `arr[].length` OR `i+1`(add the index [0] for the array)